# Zend loader extension not running

Tags: php, zend-guard

i'm really desperate.

I'm trying to encode all my php code using Zend-Guard.

So the first step is really easy i followed tutorials and i encoded all my php files, also generating a key to after decodeit.
Well the problem is when following the manual i've to load two files:

> zend_extension=full_path_to_ZendLoader.dll
>       zend_extension=full_path_to_opcache.dll

So i just copied those files inside: `php/ext`
Then i modified my `php.ini`

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\ZendLoader.dll"
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.license_path="C:\xampp\php\ext\key.zl"
```

This didn't run.
So i kept reading (stackoverflow post and from other forums) and i saw that i should have Thread Safety disabled.
So i tried to download my php with my php version (5.6) with non thread safe from https://windows.php.net/download/
So i donwload those files and i rewriteit to my php folder, but didn't work. When i exec `phpinfo()` i still see

> Thread Safety enabled

PS:I restarted apache. I'm using xampp. PHP version: 5.6

I don't know how to make those dll.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this tutorial and worked for me:

https://commaster.net/content/installing-php-fastcgi-and-zend-opcache-xampp-windows

As i've said on the question, i've to set NTS to load Zend loader